# Import csv-file to a postgres Database via postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, header

How is it possible to import a csv-file with header an ',' as delimiter into a postgres database?

I tried the following commands:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table ();
COPY my_table  FROM 'path\myData.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I get an error:

> "extra data after last expected column"

This is due to the fact that 'my_table' is empty and hasn't got any columns.
But I do not know how many columns my imported file has got.
Isn't it possible to extract this info from the header?

Comment: No. A little time with the docs [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) would have told you that per : *For COPY FROM, each field in the file is inserted, in order, into the specified column.* and *HEADER ... On input, the first line is discarded when this option is set to true (or equivalent Boolean value).*